# ASP.NET Core 1.0 - dynamically load assemblies in web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an modular asp.net core 1.0 MVC web application and I want to dynamically load assemblies on start up of the application. If I put the assembly into the root of the app (where all other assemblies are there) everything is fine, but I don't want to copy-paste the assemblies in the root, instead I want to load them from different folders.

I have tried everything I found on google/stackoverflow and nothing works so far:

- `Assembly.Load`
- `mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(moduleAssembly);`
- `DependencyContext.Load(moduleAssembly);`
- `DefaultAssemblyProvider` - apparently they removed that in asp.net core 1.0 and replaced it with `.AddApplicationPart()`

I can't figure out why none of the above works and why? Any suggestion what else I can try?

**EDIT (more info)**

I have modular based web application. The main module .dll has dependency on a class library (which is also part of the module solution). I add the main module assembly using `AddApplicationPart` but I can't succeed with the referenced class library. I get `Could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies` (in this case the dependency is only `mscorlib`). Only when I put the referenced assembly in the root web app, it works, which is not what I want.

Comment: have you tried this http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/01/19/dependency-scanning-in-asp-net-5-part-2/ ? I am yet to implement it on my service, but I came across it in my search to improve it and it looks like it should do the job

Comment: @gilmishal It uses `ILibraryManager` which is not supported in the asp.net core 1.0, I think they removed it, even the link in github gives 404

Comment: Then I will try to find an answer, sit tight

Comment: how about this? https://blog.mking.io/assembly-scanning-for-microsoft-extensions-dependency-injection/

Comment: I managed to do it using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event handler, the old way. Wasn't sure that AppDomain is still supported but it worked.